# how to calculate extremely big number?

Tags: probability

whole people in the world are playing rock-paper-scissors. how many times do we have to play untill the game draw?(with no dropout)

if we're lucky, only 1 time will be enough. but on average,how big that number is?

$\frac{1}{3^{n-1}}$ is chance to draw when $n$ is whole population.

we'll play $k$ times, so chance to draw at least 1 time is as follows$$1-(1-\frac{1}{3^{n-1}})^k$$
i want 90%.$$(1-\frac{1}{3^{n-1}})^k<0.1$$

supppose $n=6\times10^9$ and choose smallest natural number $k$.

i want to know how big $k$ is. solving with 10-base logarithm, we get $$k>\frac1{log(1+\frac1{3^{n-1}-1})}$$ since n is sooooo big, i have no calculator which is able to deal with it.

however, i got how small $\frac1{3^{n-1}-1}$is. it's near $9\times10^{-j}$ while $j=6591673730$

but i can't go any further. i tried to put into another logarithm, but it doesn't help since i don't know how small $log(1+\frac1{3^{n-1}-1})$ is.
 no way to get the number of digit of digit of.... dight k has? maybe approximation or someting?

Comment: You need a computer algebra system like Maple or Mathematica to do arbitrary precision like that.

Comment: I do not understand the meaning of "game draw" in this scenario.  The rules for multi-player rock paper scissors as I understood it was that a player is eliminated from a round in which he is participating if and only if he plays a choice which beats no other person's choice and is beaten by at least one other person's choice.  That is to say, it is a draw if all three options are selected at least once or all people choose same.  It seems that you are approaching it as though a "game draw" only occurs when all people involved choose the same thing simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

By using the well-known expansion $$\log(1+x)= x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\dots$$
we have
$$\log\left(1+(3^{n-1}-1)^{-1} \right)\approx (3^{n-1}-1)^{-1}$$
which would give you 
$$k>3^{n-1}-1\approx 3^n$$
which is such a huge number for $n=6\times 10^9$ that it doesn't really make sense to write it out (it is approximately a one with a billion zeros after it, see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5E((6*10%5E9)))).

If you want a higher precision, simply include more terms of the expansion.

Comment: I am thinking $3^{n-1}-1$ is closer to $3^{n-1}$ for $n=6\times10^9$

Comment: @SimpleArt Doesn't really matter: $6\times 10^9 -1\approx 6\times 10^9$ is a very good approximation.

Comment: Well, I am thinking $3^n$ will be $3$ times larger than $3^{n-1}-1$, approximately, and then, at the very least, the inequality might get messed up.  Better to stay within the inequality at the very least.

Comment: This is about how far you would be off: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5E((6*10%5E9))-3%5E((6*10%5E9)-1)  But I guess you could argue that it doesn't matter, given the size of $3^n$.

Comment: @Choosing $3^n$ over $3^{n-1}$ only makes us more certain that we have chosen a large enough $k$ (we need to establish a value which $k$ must be greater than).